# Why can't some keys be combined with Alt and AltGr in terminal key bindings?

Tags: keyboard-layout

I want to bind some zle function to `M-{` (i.e. Alt and '{'), but I have noticed that no matter how I write the function, the terminal never runs it when I press `M-{`.

To send `{` to the terminal, I press `AltGr-x`, so `M-{` is in reality `M-AltGr-x`.
I have ran `$ xev` to see which keypress events are received by the terminal.
Here's the result:

When I press `M-AltGr`, the terminal receives 2 events:

```
64 Alt_L
108 ISO_Level3_Shift
```

When I press 'x', the terminal receives nothing.
When I release 'x', the terminal receives 2 events:

```
64 Alt_L
108 ISO_Level3_Shift
```

---

I thought that maybe it was a fundamental limitation, and that no key could be combined with `M-AltGr`.
But after making more tests I have found out that `M-AltGr` could be combined with 'a'.

When I press `M-AltGr`, the terminal receives 2 events:

```
64 Alt_L
108 ISO_Level3_Shift
```

When I press 'a', the terminal receives 1 event:

```
24 bar
```

*because I have customized the layout so that AltGr + a emits the bar character*

---

Here's a gif to illustrate the issue.
I press `M-AltGr`, then 'a' fives times, and then 'x' five other times:

[image]

---

I tested all the keys on my keyboard, and all of them can be combined with `M-AltGr`, except these 25 ones:

```
1
6
8
keypad_3
keypad_7
keypad_8
lower than sign
CapsLock
F1
F2
F3
F5
PgDown
Tab
b
d
f
g
i
j
o
u
v
w
x
```

---

I thought that maybe the issue was in my keyboard layout, so I temporarily switched to the default English layout.
But the result seems to be identical: all keys can be combined with `M-AltGr` except the previous 25 ones.
One noticeable difference is that when I press `M-AltGr`, the terminal receives these 2 events:

```
64 Alt_L
68 Alt_R
```

Instead of:

```
64 Alt_L
108 ISO_Level3_Shift
```

---

I set the keyboard layout by running a script when the OS starts, which runs this shell command:

```
$ xkbcomp -I"$HOME/.config/keyboard/xkb" "$HOME/.config/keyboard/xkb/map" "$DISPLAY"
```

The file `~/.config/keyboard/xkb/map` contains this xkb code:

```
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(azerty)" };
    xkb_types     { include "complete"      };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete"      };
    xkb_symbols   { include "pc+fr(latin9)+programming(special_chars)+modifier(caps_ctrl)+modifier(enter_ctrl)+inet(evdev)+terminate(ctrl_alt_bksp)" };
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)"     };
};
```

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04.

---

Why can't some keys be combined with `M-AltGr`, and is there a way to fix the issue?

My goal would be to make a terminal emulator such as xterm receive the sequence `Escape {` when I press `M-AltGr-x`, just like it currently receives the sequence `Escape |` when I press `M-AltGr-a`.